# PrimeFaces custom text on Menubar

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using `<p:menubar>`. I've seen that I can use 'facet' to render custom content, like shown in the showcase.

What I want to do now, is to put a text left to the first MenuItem.

```
<h:form>
    <p:menubar autoDisplay="false">
        <f:facet name="options">
            <p:outputLabel value="My Company"/>
        </f:facet>
        <p:menuitem value="Home" outcome="index.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-pencil" style="float: right;"/>
        <p:menuitem value="Register" outcome="register.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-pencil" style="float: right;"/>
        <f:facet name="options">
            <p:commandButton action="login.xhtml" value="Login" icon="ui-icon-extlink"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:menubar>
</h:form>
```

I hope it's clear what I mean. In any case, the Outputlabel is showing up on the right side of the menubar.

Answer (score 0):

In `UIComponentBase` the facets are stored in a `private Map<String, UIComponent> facet`. So when you define multiple facets with the same name "options" they are summarized as ONE `UIComponent` in the Map (in your case an `UIPanel` with two children: `<p:outputLabel ...>` and `<p:commandButton ...>`).

When you debug through the `org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer.encodeMenu()` method (which renders your menu) you will see, that the menu consists of a list `<ul>` and every menuitem is a `<li>` tag. In the last step the "options" facet is rendered as the LAST element in this list. So both your tags appear on the right.

For example you could extend the `org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer.encodeMenu()` method in a custom Renderer class to additionally render some texts an the beginning of your menu.